# How can I return colored text in a function without having to print it in python?

Tags: python-3.x, function

I am trying to output colored text onto a webpage and I am stumped as I observed that we can get colored text only by printing and not by returning. But I need to return colored text for my purposes. This is the output I got on running print and function. [pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qt64R.png). Can anyone suggest how I could possibly return colored text?

Comment: There is no such thing as "colored text" inside Python. Any kind of coloring is applied by whatever *external* viewer/program interprets that text. Your first cell is using [ANSI escape sequences](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code), which are commonly understood by UNIX and today some Windows viewers.

Comment: If you're trying to put colored text into a webpage you need to use HTML and CSS styling, not shell escape codes.

Comment: I am quite new to using HTML and CSS. I am trying to annotate text according to different tags. I used ANSI sequences in my jupyter notebook and thought I could implement them in webpages as well. Thank you for your clarifications.

Answer (score 0):

try it with the frontend

```html
<p style="color:#ff0000;">I am red</p>
```